# How to trigger a mdl-menu using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, material-design

Can someone help me how to execute a mdl-menu (Material design lite) using javascript?
I did not find an explanation how to do it on his website.

Html code

```
<!-- Left aligned menu below button -->
<button id="demo-menu-lower-left"
        class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
  <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
</button>

<ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect"
    for="demo-menu-lower-left">
  <li class="mdl-menu__item">Some Action</li>
  <li class="mdl-menu__item mdl-menu__item--full-bleed-divider">Another Action</li>
  <li disabled class="mdl-menu__item">Disabled Action</li>
  <li class="mdl-menu__item">Yet Another Action</li>
</ul>
```

the screen shot : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLy1C.png)

Comment: Website says how to implement this here: https://getmdl.io/components/#menus-section

Comment: @hackerrdave yap.. but there is no javascript explanation

Comment: as long as you load the mdl js library via `<script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.min.js"></script>` (or other means) you'll get the menu functionality as long as you use the right classes.

Comment: @hackerrdave that is the trouble, i made my web using ajax, so the mdl library is just loaded once. when i navigate the page, i need to register again the event handler of all material design componen, but there is no explanation how to do that

Comment: ahh I see - take a look at this thread: https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/871 they recommend `componentHandler.upgradeDom('MaterialMenu', 'mdl-menu');`

Comment: @hackerrdave, its work very well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following command to re-initialize the menu:

`componentHandler.upgradeDom('MaterialMenu', 'mdl-menu');`

According to the [source code](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/blob/mdl-1.x/src/mdlComponentHandler.js) this: "Searches existing DOM for elements of our component type and upgrades them if they have not already been upgraded."

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to trigger a 'click' event on it (try the following code in javascript console of [this page](https://getmdl.io/components/#menus-section)):

```
// the button of 3 vertical dots
var button = document.querySelector('#demo-menu-lower-left');

// create a "click" event and dispatch it to button
var ev = new Event('click');
button.dispatchEvent(ev);
```

Or, we can also use `inspector` developer tool of browser to find the event handler of the button, and learn from that.

Comment: yah.. but my case is, i need to re-register the MaterialMenu, because i made a web using html5 history API, so the header an footer are static. when the main container is loaded by ajax, the event handler is need to re-register again..